# How i can show a small image from url content in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, web

How i can show a small image from url content in c#?,

for preview page of a url link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was recently told that you could use the web browser control and draw the bitmap.

I did a quick Google search and found an example:

http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/07/C-Generate-WebPage-Thumbmail-Screenshot-Image.aspx

However, the web browser control is in the System.Windows.Forms namespace.